# Error in building pdf from Latex file created by latexdiff

Tags: latexdiff

I am using `latexdiff` to highlight changes in latex files.
I made the latex file using `latexdiff`. When I want to build the PDF file, I get many errors like:

```
Paragraph ended before \caption@prepareanchor was complete. ... the networks. }\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin }
```

and

```
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. ... the networks. }\DIFdelend \DIFaddbegin }
```

Does anyone know what is about and how can I solve it?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with a caption

Comment: There is not enough information in the question. Please provide an MWE (Minimum Working(Failing) Example): old file, new file, and what latexdiff produces

Comment: `latexdiff` only works for the simplest of latex files...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your preamble - I'll remove the answer if that is not it.

```
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}\definecolor{BLUE}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\protect\color{blue}\uwave{#1}}}
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}}
\providecommand{\DIFaddbegin}{} 
\providecommand{\DIFaddend}{} 
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} 
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} 
\providecommand{\DIFaddFL}[1]{\DIFadd{#1}} 
\providecommand{\DIFdelFL}[1]{\DIFdel{#1}} 
\providecommand{\DIFaddbeginFL}{} 
\providecommand{\DIFaddendFL}{} 
\providecommand{\DIFdelbeginFL}{} 
\providecommand{\DIFdelendFL}{}
```